# SQL Server Substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

When the following query is executed if fails to run unless the 2nd substring statement (commented out here) is uncommmented. What is going on here that I am missing?

Uses the Northwind database

```
SELECT Substring(Contactname, Charindex(' ', Contactname) + 1, Len(Contactname))AS LastName, 
       Substring(Contactname, 1, Charindex(' ', Contactname) - 1)  AS FirstName1 
       --, substring(ContactName, 1, 4) AS FirstName2  
       -- if this line is commented out then the query crashes with the error msg 
       --Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. 
       , 
       Phone, 
       Orderid, 
       Orderdate 
FROM   customers 
       INNER JOIN orders 
               ON customers.Customerid = orders.Customerid
```

Comment: Runs fine with all substring statements, but not with 2 of the 3?  That makes no sense.  What is the error?

Comment: @GoatCO - The error is in the question. `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function`

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah missed that.

Answer (score 5):

```
Charindex(' ', Contactname) - 1
```

Returns `-1` if `Contactname` does not contain a space. This is an invalid length parameter.

There must be a `Contactname` that causes the `Substring` expression to fail but that is filtered out by the `JOIN`.

Presumably the compute scalar shifts around between the two plans and happens to be evaluated after the join when you have that line uncommented.

See [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) for some discussion on this type of issue.

A way around this would be to append a space to the input to `Charindex`

```
Substring(Contactname, 1, Charindex(' ', Contactname + ' ' ) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch out for the negative cases.  A null value, a empty string, or a one name person.

I used a Common Table Expression since I did not want the charindex() function all over the place.

Also, your first substring() did not substract the correct amount of characters.

```
-- Use the sample db
use [Northwind]
go

-- Watch out for null & one name
;
with cteContactsOrders
as
(
SELECT 
  Contactname as FullName,
  Substring(IsNull(Contactname, ''), 1, 4) as FirstFour,
  Charindex(' ', IsNull(Contactname, '')) as Pos,
  Phone, 
  Orderid,
  Orderdate 
FROM   
  customers as c
INNER JOIN 
  orders as o
ON 
  c.Customerid = o.Customerid 
)
select 
    co.*,

    case 
   when Pos > 0 then substring(FullName, 1, Pos-1) 
   when Pos = 0 and len(ltrim(rtrim(FullName))) > 0 then FullName
   else ''
    end as FirstName,

    case 
       when Pos > 0 then substring(FullName, Pos+1, len(FullName) - Pos) 
       else ''
    end as LastName
from 
    cteContactsOrders co
```

The output on SQL Server 2014 CTP2.

[image]

Comment: `Substring(Contactname, 1, Charindex(' ', Contactname + ' ' ) - 1)` works correctly for all those cases. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30252)